# Creating plugins for electronjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Below is my requirement.

1. My application will have many modules. Each modules going to serve as separate plugin.
2. I am creating a main electron js application which is going to hold each modules. Like a pluggable interface.
3. Each modules will run inside the main application in a separate tabs. Each tabs represent each modules. So that i can have any number of modules which can be easily scalable and embedded in the main application.
4. How can i achieve this interfacing architecture in electronjs (javascript)?

Please suggest me some ideas to implement such scenario.

Comment: Hi, I'm building an application with similar requirements. Did your investigations lead you to any conclusions regarding creating a plugin system for an electron application? Any best practices or useful libraries?

Comment: I haven't got any proper solution for this. so i switched to mono. Cross platform, very good community support. I got what i need in mono.